# Regex advanced way to replace with many expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I didn't find a solution inside **regex's** documentation for my current problem. I'm using javascript, html.
My code is like this:

```
var text = 'This [close](animal) is a dog';
```

I want to get this using **regex**:

```
'This {animal} is a dog';
```

what I mean, i want to have **'close'** replaced with **{** and **}**.
I know, there's a solution like:

```
var res = text.replace('[close](','{').replace(')','}');
```

but in my case, I have many rules and I don't want to duplicate that line to do so. Sometimes I'm using other replacement like **'[ xxxxx ]'**.
Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid the question isn't clear as it currently stands. Perhaps examples of those other "rules"? In particular, do they change what you do with `animal`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's actually quite clear :-)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy - It actually isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
var text = 'This [close](animal) is a dog';
console.log(text.replace(/\[[^\][]*]\(([^()]*)\)/g, '{$1}'));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rrKfwf/1).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\(` - a `](` substring
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The `{$1}` replacement is the contents of the capturing group enclosed with braces.

If you can only have two values - `close` and `open` - inside `[...]`, and replace `close` with `{...}` and `open` with `}...{`, you may use

```js
var text = '[open](animal)This [close](animal) is a dog';
console.log(text.replace(/\[(open|close)]\(([^()]*)\)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { 
  return $1==='close' ? '{'+$2+'}' : '}'+$2+'{';})
);
```

Comment: it works perfectly but if i change [close] with [open], it returns the same result, that's not good, e.g: i want to have }animal{ with [open]

Comment: @pitiful Please provide a sample string with expected output. Note you may replace `[^\][]*` with `open` or `close`, as you wish, but there can be better solutions if you explain the scenario *exactly*. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, that you can pass custom regex in `Array.prototype.replace`. In your case it would be `text.replace(/[close](/g,'{')`. Full solution of your question will look like:

```
var res = res.replace(/\[\w+\]\((.*)\)/, (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
  return `{${b}}`;
});
```

The brackets around `.*` used to 'capture' animal inside variable `b`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), I'v found a solution by what you said

```
var res0 = text.replace(/\[close]\(([^()]*)\)/g, '{$1}');
var res1 = text.replace(/\[open]\(([^()]*)\)/g, '}$1{');
```

Sorry if i did miskates, i'm not used to english expression so :-)

Comment: I have included a solution to do that in a single step. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53060425/3832970).

Comment: well explained and solved my problem, Thank you very much